# kafka 0.10.2 describe logdir( Partitions info per broker)

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka supports describeLogDirs api from version `1.0.0` or higher.

But is there any way to get logDirs data for kafka broker version `0.10.2`.

The reason i wanted the logdirs data for each broker, is to get the partition info( like size and offset of partition per broker).

Comment: Why not SSH to the nodes and `df` the files?

Comment: ok. this will only get size of a partition. But about offset lag of a partition in a broker.

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question... Use `kafka-consumer-groups` or install Burrow